# Why can't I assign 2 to all the elements in an array in C/C++ by this way?

Tags: c++

My system is Ubuntu

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#define LEN 16

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[16] = {2};
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

I compiled it by this command in terminal : `g++ t1.cpp -o t1 && ./t1`

but the result is

```
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Array initialization does exactly what you see. It sets the elements given in the initializer, and then sets all elements not specified to `0`. See [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) (for C++)

Comment: The answer to the "why not" is because the language specification is quite explicit about initialization, and it does not work the way you are expecting. Just use `std::fill` if you wish to populate the array with the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Any decent book, tutorial or class should have taught you that the definition

```
int a[16] = {2};
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[16] = {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

If you want to initialize all elements to a single value you need to explicitly do it.

You can also use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) after definition to set every element to a value:

```
int a[16];
std::fill(begin(a), end(a), 2);
```

---

And some nitpicking: What you're doing is *initialization*, not assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned *a* `2` to index `0` of your array.

You may wish to use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill).

```
const int size = 16;

int main() {
    int a[size];

    std::fill(a, a + size, 2);

    return 0;
}
```